# -o /publish/' returned a non-zero code: 1

Tags: dockerfile

below is my Dockerfile.

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build as build-image

WORKDIR /home/app

COPY *.sln ./
COPY ./*/*.csproj ./
RUN for file in $(ls *.csproj); do mkdir -p ./${file%.*}/ && mv $file ./${file%.*}/; done

RUN dotnet restore

COPY . .

RUN dotnet publish ./SampleProj -o /publish/

WORKDIR /publish

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SampleProj.dll"]
```

I am getting error "-o /publish/' returned a non-zero code: 1:.

Comment: For those encountering a similar issue: You may try to add the "-v diag" flag (verbosity diagnostic) to the dotnet publish in your Dockerfile to get a more detailed info about what's causing the error.